# Bounds for summing Continuous Variable

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

I have a question on how the bounds are picked for the example below:
Given that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent random variables, and the pdf is $f_{X_i}(x_i) = λe^{−λx}, x_i > 0$ Find $W=X_1+X_2$

I got:
$\int_0^{\infty} f(x)f(w-x)$, but apparently the upper bound is $w$. Also, I was wondering whether the function inside needs to always be a positive number since the explanation says that f(x) >0 without the question explicitly mentioning it.
I don't understand why the upper bound is $w$.

Comment: $0<X_1<X_1+X_2=W$. Note that $f(w-x)$ in your integral becomes $0$ if $w-x<0$ or $x>w$.

Comment: Thanks, but why can't $f(w-x)$ be 0 or smaller? is it a universal rule?

Comment: If a function you are integrating is $0$ in some interval then the integral over that interval is also $0$, so you need not integrate over that interval.  For example, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)dx=\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)dx$ if $f(x)$ for $x<0$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. For a function $f(0)$, what if the function is a constant variable then like f(x) = 3?. Then by integrating it u get 3x?

Answer (score 1):

You actually have $$f_W(w)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X_1}(x)f_{X_2}(w-x)\,dx$$

but here $f_{X_1}(x)=0$ for $x\le 0$ and $f_{X_2}(w-x)=0$ for $w-x\le 0$ i.e. for $x\ge w$, so you could write this using indicator functions as $$f_W(w)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} λe^{−λx}I_{[x>0]}λe^{−λ(w-x)}I_{[x<w]}\,dx$$

so the integrand is only non-zero when $0 < x < w$.  This means that when $w>0$ you can then take the indicator functions into the limits of the integral as $$f_W(w)=\int_{0}^{w} λe^{−λx}λe^{−λ(w-x)}\,dx$$ for $w>0$, and it is easy to see this is $f_W(w)=\int_{0}^{w} λ^2e^{−λw}\,dx=wλ^2e^{−λw}$. For $w \le 0$ the integral is $0$.

Comment: Hi, thanks but I still don't get why $f_{X_1} (x) = 0$ for $x\le{0}$. Also when you use that $F_W(w)$ equation, it looks like you're about a general example rather than the specific equation of $λ^{−λ}$. Is that correct to assume that?

Comment: @Mathhurtsmybrain You said at the start "$f_{X_i}(x_i) = λe^{−λx}, x_i > 0$" implicitly suggesting you also have $f_{X_i}(x_i) =0, x_i \le 0$ - and you need something like that if you want this to be a density on the real numbers.  In your attempt you had $f(x)f(w-x)$ and this also helps answer the question of what value this product takes when $x > w$

Comment: Sorry, but I still can't wrap my head around it being implicitly suggested in the question. If it's an exponential function, then wouldn't the only time it'll be 0 is when there's a limit of x approaching infinity? In the question it wasn't specified what $x_i$ could be?

Comment: @Mathhurtsmybrain This particular issue is what happens to the product of the densities $f(x)f(w-x)$ when $x \le 0$ or when $w-x\le 0$ (with $w-x\le 0 \iff x\ge w$)